# How can I alias initialize method in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I feel it is weird to create an object by calling "new", but in class definition the initializer  is called "initialize". I tried to make it consistent(to be called "new" in both class definition and outside) so I tried the code below using alias_method:

```
class Class
    alias_method :initialize :new
end

class Foo
    def new
        puts "bar"
    end
end

f = Foo.new
```

I thought when I alias `new` as `initialize`, it will call `initialize`, and `initialize` is the alias of `new` so it will call `new`. But it is not working, and give errors:

```
SyntaxError: test.rb:2: syntax error, unexpected ':'

    alias_method :initialize :new
                              ^
```

Apparently `new` is a key word and cannot be aliased. But any way around?

---

Update:

Sorry I missed the comma in the `alias_method`

After adding the comma, the script runs without error. But it does not output "bar" so new method is not called. I am not sure why this will not work as comments below...

Comment: Note that you should be using `alias_method :initialize, :new` (note the comma); however, I think this simply cannot be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea what the implications are for overriding `Object#initialize`. I wouldn't sleep well at night with this in my code but how about something like:

```
class Object
  def initialize
    new if self.respond_to?(:new)
  end
end

class Foo
  def new
    puts "BAR"
  end
end

Foo.new
```

Comment: That's the way it is! It gives warning about infinite loop, and I changed the `object` to `BasicObject`, and it works perfect!

Comment: @texasbruce This will break any scripts which use `Class.new` to create a new class, because when the new class is created it will then have `new` called on it again, returning an *instance* of the new class rather than the class itself

Comment: Ye I had that concern before, but then I realize the new method is private and not accessible outside, so system `Class.new` will be called first. After object created, when we call new again, the Class.new will not be called because Foo.new overrides that one (all my assumption)

Comment: One supporting fact is that if I do not define new method in `Class Foo`, it will give error: `new method is not defined.` So the `Class.new` is not called

Answer (score 7):

Note that `initialize` and `new` do different things. Specifically, `new` is a class method and `initialize` is an instance method.

`new` is responsible for creating an "new" object, assigning memory etc, and then once the object is created it is then `initialize`d, by asking it to set itself up.

`new` can certainly be overridden, as shown in [this blog example](http://www.mindbucket.com/2009/02/11/ruby-overriding-classnew-to-make-custom-wrapper-pattern/), but almost certainly you don't want to do this unless you have a very good reason.

Comment: Can "initialize" be overridden?

Comment: of course, that's the main way of customising the way a class is created

Answer (score 1):

The error is not just about the new being a keyword but your syntax for the alias_method is also wrong. As the error specifies you need to put a "," between the 2 function names. In your case the correct syntax would be:

```
alias_method :initialise, :new
```

The default format for alias_method is as follows:

```
alias_method :new_function_name, :old_function_name.
```

Also you should note that the "alias_method" is no longer considered good programming practice in rails and you should use the "super" keyword with corresponding conditional statements.